# Select query of wmi used to view the process which has max usage of cpu

Tags: process, wmi, wmi-query

What is the query used to view the topmost process which is having maximum usage of CPU using WMI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class.

```
Select IDProcess, Name, PercentProcessorTime from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process
```

Once you have those informations you can sort by PercentProcessorTime. It should work fine.